# How to add To do notes in Table

Tags: tables, todonotes

Im using todonotes package and run in to a problem with it, when in a Table. I get a Float(s) lost error.
How can i use todonotes package in a tablecell?

MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \usepackage{xkeyval}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
    \usepackage{calc}
    \usepackage[
    german,
    textsize=tiny
    ]{todonotes}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    some more text
    and \todo[fancyline]{PSP Nr.} some more 
     \lipsum[2]
    \begin{table}[htp]
      \caption{default}
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{7cm}}
          narrow text in table & some more narrow text in table\\
          narrow text in table1 & some more %\todo[fancyline]{PSP Nr.} % <-- include this
          narrow text in table1\\
        \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
      \label{default}
    \end{table}%
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic problem is that you try to place a float inside of a float. You could use the workaround for footnotes (which are also floats) presented in the `todonotes`-documentation, loading the `marginnotes`-package and replace `\marginpar` with `\marginnote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[
german,
textsize=tiny
]{todonotes}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%important part starts here
\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand{\marginpar}{\marginnote}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
some more text
and \todo[fancyline]{PSP Nr.} some more 
 \lipsum[2]
\begin{table}[htp]
  \caption{default}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{7cm}}
      narrow text in table & some more narrow text in table\\
      narrow text in table1 & some more\todo[fancyline]{PSP Nr.} % <-- include this
      narrow text in table1\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  \label{default}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You did my day at a level I can't imagine....This issue have been frustrating me for 3 years. Thanks